# Prove $\limsup_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)\leq\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n+\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I've been self studying real analysis and I'm trying to prove $\limsup_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)\leq\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n+\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n$ using the definition $\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sup_{k\ge n}a_n\right)$. Here's my attempt:

The strategy is to show $\sup_{k\ge n}(a_k+b_k)\leq\sup_{k\ge n}a_n+\sup_{k\ge n}b_n$, then use the order limit theorem to establish the inequality in the limiting process.

First, we see that $\sup_{k\ge n}a_n\ge a_k$ and $\sup_{k\ge n}b_n\ge b_k$ for all $k\ge n$, which implies $\sup_{k\ge n}a_n+\sup_{k\ge n}b_n\ge a_k+b_k$ for all $k\ge n.$ In particular, this shows $\sup_{k\ge n}a_n+\sup_{k\ge n}b_n$ is an upper bound of the set $\{a_k+b_k:k\ge n\}$, so we have that $\sup_{k\ge n}(a_k+b_k)\leq\sup_{k\ge n}a_n+\sup_{k\ge n}b_n$ because the left hand side is the *least* upper bound of the set. Now take the limit on both sides and we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sup_{k\ge n}(a_k+b_k)\right)\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sup_{k\ge n}a_n\right)+\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sup_{k\ge n}b_n\right)$$
or
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)\leq\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n+\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n.$$

Is my proof valid?

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct.

Comment: Since your proof is more or less correct and the problem had been asked before, I voted to closed as a duplicate. Note, though, at several lines you should have $\sup_{k\ge n} a_k$ instead of $\sup_{k\ge n } a_n$.