# $\|x\|_{p} \rightarrow\|x\|_{\infty}$ as $p \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: solution-verification, lp-spaces, normed-spaces

The following question came in my quiz:

> (True/False) Let $x \in \ell^{p_{0}}$ for some $1 \leq p_{0}<\infty .$ Then $\|x\|_{p} \rightarrow\|x\|_{\infty}$ as $p \rightarrow \infty$.

Where $\ell^{p}=\left\{x=\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots\right): \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{j}\right|^{p}<\infty\right\}$ for $1 \leq p<\infty$,
$
\|x\|_{p}=\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{j}\right|^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ and $\|x\|_{\infty}=\sup_{j \in \mathbb{N}}\left|x_{j}\right|$. I answered it true and gave the following reason:

Let $x \in \ell^{p_{0}}$ for some $1 \le p_{0}<\infty$, then $x \in \ell^{p}$ $\forall\, p \ge p_{0}$ since $\ell^{p_{0}} \subset \ell^{p}$. This implies $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{j}\right|^{p}$ is finite $\forall\, p \ge p_{0}$. If $\|x\|_{\infty}=0$, then $x=0$ and the convergence is trivial. If $\|x\|_{\infty}\ne0$, then $$\tag{1} \|x\|_{p}=\|x\|_{\infty}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\left|x_{j}\right|}{\|x\|_{\infty}}\right)^{p}\right)^{1 / p}.$$
Since $\lim _{j \rightarrow \infty}\left|x_{j}\right|=0$, the sequence $\left(\left|x_{n}\right|\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to zero and $ \sup _{j \in \mathbb{N}}\left\{\left|x_{j}\right|\right\}=\left|x_{j^{\prime}}\right|$ for some $j^{\prime} \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $J:=\left\{j \in \mathbb{N}:| x_{j}|=\|x\|_{\infty}\right\}$, then $J$ is non empty $\left(j^{\prime} \in J\right)$ and the cardinality of $J$ is finite (otherwise $\left.\|x\|_{\infty}=0\right)$. Therefore, $ \displaystyle\lim_{p \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left|x_{j}\right|^{p}}{||x||_{\infty}^{p}} = |J|+ \lim_{p \to \infty}\sum_{j \notin J}\frac{\left|x_{j}\right|^{p}}{||x||_{\infty}^{p}}$ and since $\sum\left|x_{j}\right|^{p}$ is finite $\forall\, p \ge p_{0}$, $\sum \frac{\left|x_{j}\right|^{p}}{||x||_{\infty}^{p}}$ is also finite. Thus $$\tag{2} \lim_{p \to \infty} \sum_{ j\notin J} \frac{\left|x_{j}\right|^{p}}{||x||_{\infty}^{p}} = \sum_{j \notin J} \lim_{p \to \infty} \frac{\left|x_{j}\right|^{p}}{||x||_{\infty}^{p}} = 0 $$ and the result follows from $(1)$, as $||x||_{p} = ||x||_{\infty} $exp$\left( \frac{1}{p} \ln{\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left|x_{j}\right|^{p}}{||x||_{\infty}^{p}}}\right)$

However, the explanation in the answer sheet is marked incorrect. I don't understand where my mistake it.

Comment: Your (2) is incorrect, you cannot exchange infinite sum and limit in general

Comment: Is it not possible to exchange the limit and sum here ? @ArcticChar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit of $\|x\|_p$ as $p\rightarrow\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669051/limit-of-x-p-as-p-rightarrow-infty)

Comment: I wanted to verify my answer, and look for possible mistakes. How does that link answer my question ? @OliverDiaz

Comment: @Sam: this types of questions have been studied several times before in MSE, I am not critizising your solution, but you could benefit b y doing some research about what is done in MSE. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3739548/121671) is another example of your problem in a more general setting, there many. more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if $\{y_n(p)\}$ is a sequence (depending on $p$), then

$$ \lim_{p\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n(p) = \sum_{n=1} ^\infty \lim_{p\to \infty} y_n(p)$$
might not hold. For example, if $y_n(p) = 1$ when $p<n$ and $0$ otherwise, then

$$+\infty =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n(p) \neq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lim_{p\to \infty } y_n(p) = 0$$

But in your case, (2) actually holds. However you would need an argument for it (e.g. it follows from monotone convergence theorem).

However you don't need (2). Instead, we have (for all $p\ge p_0$, where $p_0$ is fixed)

$$ |J|^{1/p} \le \left( |J| + \sum_{n\notin J} \left(\frac{\left|x_{j}\right|}{\|x\|_{\infty}}\right)^{p}\right)^{1/p} \le \left( |J| + \sum_{n\notin J}\left(\frac{\left|x_{j}\right|}{\|x\|_{\infty}}\right)^{p_0}\right)^{1/p} $$
taking $p\to\infty$ and use squeeze theorem, we have

$$\lim_{p\to \infty}  \left( |J| + \sum_{n\notin J} \left(\frac{\left|x_{j}\right|}{\|x\|_{\infty}}\right)^{p}\right)^{1/p} =1.$$

Comment: This is a duplicate. People at CURED are quick to call others out and even downvote when answer duplicated, but they don't apply the same criteria to themselves.

Comment: @OliverDiaz my take on "solution verification" question is that I only vote to close when their attempts is correct and is in the duplicate (like what I did [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4236603/prove-limsup-n-to-inftya-nb-n-leq-limsup-n-to-inftya-n-limsup-n-to-in#comment8803799_4236603)). When I find some mistakes worth pointing out, I write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should be true. As you have stated if $x\in\mathcal l_1$ then $|x_k|\to 0$. Thus $|x_k|$ takes a maximum. WLOG we can assume that this maximum is $1$ (else divide by this maximum, as for any norm we have $||x/c||=||x||/|c|$). Thus $|x_k|\leq 1$.

Then:
$$ 1 \leq ||x||_p^p = \sum_{k} |x_k|^p \leq \sum_{k} 1^{p-1}|x_k| = ||x||_1 $$
Thus
$$ 1\leq ||x||_p \leq \sqrt[p]{||x||_1} \to 1$$